# Remove rectangle around ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, listboxitem

[image]

Above is an image of my listboxitem.
I am wondering whether it is possible to remove the rectangle that surronds the ellipse.
Padding and BorderThicknes are 0 already.

I use this styling:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> ...
   <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data}" Value="ellipse">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Brush}" Stroke="Black"/>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Int}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I tried this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Then the items are not selectable any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the 'Rectangle' that you're talking about is just the `ListBoxItem.Background`. It also *looks* like the default selection `Color` used in the `ListBox` control. If that's what it is, you can easily hide this by setting some property values in a local `Resources` section. Try adding these to your `ListBox.Resources` section:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
</Style.Resources>
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can use these same properties to set the colour of the default selection too.

Answer (score 6):

[You should create control template for ListBoxItem.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Then you can change background of ListBoxItem.

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
           TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                            BorderThickness="2"
                            Padding="2"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                    Property="Background"
                                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.Transparent}" />

                            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                    Property="BorderBrush"
                                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.WhiteSmoke}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{x:Static Brushes.Transparent}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Datas}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="30"
                             Height="30"
                             Fill="{Binding Path=EllipseBrush}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}"/>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Sample you can download [here](https://vk0p2w.dm2303.livefilestore.com/y2pEJiJvHTP-fzZ1UkFn0A7SjGefE3w4Qa9yRGe_sA-BD5_hEOhygso8SbiP5FvVWRHJlP4N9VHjrw0wY-sSz73oHAtjwh20rK65Lfu0l4p09o/ListBoxItemControlTemplate.zip?download&psid=1)

Comment: This solution is not satisfactory because the selection of listboxitem does not work anymore - compare my question while trying simply `<ContentPresenter />` for controltemplate.

Comment: What you mean selection of ListBoxItem does not work anymore? Please download may sample app a a test i. Link you can find in my answer.

Comment: @Sheridan: Simple control template is lot of work ? IMHO control template is cleaner way for this task. Change system colors is only workaround.

Comment: You are right, the selection just doesn't work in my own example, in yours it is just fine!

Comment: @Gerad: Now is clear. Important is that you solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, your 50+ lines *are* a lot of work *for this requirement*... your 50+ lines does exactly what this *single* line does: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />`. Sure, *if* the question author was requesting a new look for a UI element, then a `ControlTemplate` would be the way to go.... but just to change one colour? Not so much.

Comment: Author of the question first tried solve this problem with control template but he was not successful because his style with control template was not completed hence I provide to him solution with control template. He didn’t ask for the easiest solution ;). But now we spam this site hence I quit this debate. Ok?